# Error 0x80070070 when installing Windows 11 via Bootcamp Mac Pro 7,1

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I am a little stumped on this and hoping someone can help.  I am trying to install Windows 11 via bootcamp on my Mac Pro 7,1.  I edited the registry as instructed here to bypass the TPM check (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auET5iNvQos)

The error seems to bring up something about not enough free space to install everything, however I made the partition 164GB which should be more than enough

Can anybody direct me towards a solution to fix this

Comment: Provide a screenshot of disk management showing your partition layout by editing your question. The registry key isn’t the correct key to bypass the TPM requirement by the way. The correct key is **AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU**

Comment: Just checking you do mean the 2019 behemoth, not the 2010 laptop. I'd also be far more inclined to see how TwoCanoes do it rather than some random interweb video. See https://twocanoes.com/install-windows-11-without-tpm-2-on-boot-camp/